# morphia aggregation distinct map keys

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, morphia

I have a mongo collection with one of the columns as map. For example :

```
   "_id" : ObjectId("5621b"),
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2015-09-29T14:27:37.451Z"),
    "comment" : "this is my votes",
    "attributes" : {
        "java" : "great",
        "perl" : "good",
        "ruby" : "so so",
         }
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5621c"),
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2015-09-29T15:03:25.948Z"),
    "comment" : "foo",
    "attributes" : {
        "perl" : "old fashioned",
        "java" : "best of all",
        "bash" : "very usefull",
        "lisp" : "plan to learn",
         }
```

I am working with java and morphia and want to get  some kind of aggregation

```
 datastore.createAggregation(LanguageComments.class)
      .group(
```

where I can distinct get all keys of the attributes map:
**java, perl, ruby, bash, lisp**

Comment: MongoDB cannot traverse keys without resorting to JavaScript processing. You would be better off with a a structure in an array like: `[{ "name": "perl", "value": "old fashioned" },{ "name": "java", "value": "great"}]`. So now there is a consistent path to `attributes.name` from which to get the distinct information. Otherwise you are stuck with mapReduce. Changing the structure will benefit you in a lot more ways.

Answer (score 0):

db.yourcollectionname.distinct('attributes') will produce the following result for the sample data shown above

[
        {
                "java" : "great",
                "perl" : "good",
                "ruby" : "so so"
        },
        {
                "perl" : "old fashioned",
                "java" : "best of all",
                "bash" : "very usefull",
                "lisp" : "plan to learn"
        }
]

or you can use the aggregate query

db.yourcollectionname.aggregate([{$group:{_id:'$attributes'}}])

It will give you the following result

{ "_id" : { "perl" : "old fashioned", "java" : "best of all", "bash" : "very usefull", "lisp" : "plan to learn" } }

{ "_id" : { "java" : "great", "perl" : "good", "ruby" : "so so" } }

Choose which query is most appropriate for your scenario, execute that query and put the output in a java Map.